# Show divs with children fading in and out

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to loop through a set of divs (latest_holder[n]) and have their grandchildren (latest_imageholder) fade in and out starting with having the first visible on load.

My HTML looks like this:

```
        <div class="row latest_holder0">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row latest_holder1">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row latest_holder2">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row latest_holder3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        ...etc
```

As you can see, there's no telling if latest_holder[n] has 1 or more grandchildren.

I tries something like this:

```
( function($) {
    "use strict";
    $(window).load( function() {
        $("div[class^='latest_holder']").each(function() {
            $(".latest_imageholder").each(function() {
                (function fadeItems(elem){   
                    elem.fadeIn('slow',function(){      
                       $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){   
                           if($(this).next().length > 0){
                             fadeItems($(this).next());   
                           } 
                           else{
                               setTimeout(fadeItems, 0, $("div.latest_imageholder:first"));
                           }
                       }); 
                    });
                })( $("div.latest_imageholder:first") );
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But that only loops the first div.

Also I'd like to have the first div visible for about 3 seconds before I start fading to the next one, if there is one...

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout with the `index` returned by each like :

```
setTimeout(function() {
   self.fadeIn('slow');
}, index * 500);
```

```js
(function($) {
  $(".latest_imageholder").hide();

  $("div[class*='latest_holder']").each(function() {
    $(".latest_imageholder", this).each(function(index, elem) {
      var self = $(this);

      setTimeout(function() {
        self.fadeIn('slow');
      }, index * 500);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row latest_holder0">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row latest_holder1">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row latest_holder2">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row latest_holder3">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="latest_imageholder">image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that what you was looking for ?